# Class constructor dependency with multiple instances of the same class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor

I am not sure if it's reasonable to pass the class itself in the constructor, like this:

```
class OngoingActions {
  constructor(Activation) {
    this._actions = {
      onTurnStart: [new Activation(), new Activation()],
      onTurnEnd: [new Activation(), new Activation()],
      onDraw: [new Activation(), new Activation()],
      onMove: new Activation()
    };
  }
}
```

I understand that for dependency injection you need to pass an instance of the class. It would feel a bit akward to pass 7 or more instances of the same class in the constructor. I could also import the whole '_actions' object, but it feels nice to see the structure of the object in the same class. What would be the best aproach to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for `factory pattern`, It means factory class has to know the `object class`. And `generate function` should not be instance function instead it should be `static`. So that only one `source for truth`.

```js
class Activation {
  constructor(event) {
    this.event = event;
  }
}
class OnGoingActionFactory {}
OnGoingActionFactory.getActions = () => {
  return {
    onTurnStart: [new Activation("start"), new Activation("start2")],
    onTurnEnd: [new Activation("end"), new Activation("end")],
    onDraw: [new Activation(), new Activation()],
    onMove: new Activation(),
  };
};

console.log(OnGoingActionFactory.getActions())
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. You and Jozef both provided an answer that helped me to understand. Since you had an example I accept yours. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to use dependency injection for `Activation` class?

Are you planning to check if `this._actions` is initialized using only this class instances? Does the `Activation` class stores some internal state which depends on number of instances created?

Sounds like factory pattern to me.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right, I don't do any of that. So If I want to swap between different `Activation` classes, I should use factory to do that instead of DI.